# Getting baseclass property value using reflection - base.Property as opposed to this.Property

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I want to know if something like this is possible: I've overriden a property of a base class, which is auto-implemented. I've supplied logic in the override to resolve "missing" properties against default settings.

Now, I want to use reflection to check whether the default value is used or some "actual" value. In other words, I need to check if `base.Property` is null, but by using reflection. This doesn't work, it simply gets the sub-class value (which is resolved against defaults, so not null).

```
var property = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
if(property.GetValue(this, null) == null))
    OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
```

Also tried:

```
var property = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
if(property.GetValue(this, null) == null))
    OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
```

Is it possible using reflection to access the base class value?

UPDATE:

Following advice from comments, I tried the following, just for kicks.

```
var method1 = this.GetType().BaseType.GetMethods().First(x => x.Name.Contains(e.PropertyName));
var method = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetGetMethod();
var methodValue = method1.Invoke(this, null);
```

Both of these still return the "derived" value, while at the same time `base.Property` returns null.

Comment: @Tigran Yes it is, otherwise I couldn't override it, righT?

Comment: you can use "new", it depends..

Comment: @Tigran oh yes, true. But I want these properties to be properly overriden when I pass around this class as its base class.

Comment: I tried in different ways, and it doesn't seems to me possible, honestly. May be to identify DEFAULT value, it's enoug to have public static fields that describes every single DEFAULT value fro every single property, so you can compare when you want. BUt why do you ned use reflection for this?

Comment: @Tigran No it doesn't seem like it is, not according to other answers either. It would just have been a convenient, if ugly, way of checking if the value was "set" or "default"

Comment: using reflection for checking default value, doesn't seems to rafinate too, honestly. May be you can find some other nice solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, although as far as I know there's no way to do it without emitting your own IL, basically using the [`call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx) instruction rather than [`callvirt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt.aspx).

Note that if you need to go to these lengths to make your design work then that's a sign that you're probably doing something wrong somewhere!

Anyway, here's a contrived example. (Error-checking etc omitted for brevity.)

```
var derived = new DerivedClass();
Console.WriteLine(derived.GetBaseProperty("Prop"));    // displays "BaseProp"

// ...

public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Prop { get; set;}
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override string Prop { get; set;}

    public DerivedClass()
    {
        base.Prop = "BaseProp";
        this.Prop = "DerivedProp";
    }

    public object GetBaseProperty(string propName)
    {
        Type t = this.GetType();
        MethodInfo mi = t.BaseType.GetProperty(propName).GetGetMethod();

        var dm = new DynamicMethod("getBase_" + propName, typeof(object), new[] { typeof(object) }, t);

        ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi);
        if (mi.ReturnType.IsValueType) il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, mi.ReturnType);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var getBase = (Func<object, object>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, object>));
        return getBase(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but as you rightly say, needing to do this is probably a sign that you made a wrong turn somewhere in your design ;). And it sort of puts me at ease to see that it is not so straightforward to do.

Comment: This only works because you have no backing field. You're simply storing two literals. The OP specified that the base property is auto-implemented.

Comment: @Charles: Oops, that's what I get for writing code like this when I haven't had enough sleep (and not testing properly either). Should hopefully be fixed now, and I've updated the example to use auto-properties too.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK I think it is not possible. The *real* type of the object is the derived type, and by definition of *virtual* methods, no matter through which type instance (actual type or base type) you call a method, you will get the overriden implementation.

Having this work any other way would be, at least to me, unexpected behavior.

**EDIT**: I have tried the following to see if it is actually possible to get to the base implentation:

```
Type baseType = this.GetType().BaseType;
var methodInfo = baseType.GetMethod("Foo");
string foo = methodInfo.Invoke(this, null); //Derived type implementation
```

This means that even calling the method through the `base` type `MethodInfo` reflection is able to resolve the override and will return the derived implementation. So I think what you are trying is not possible through reflection or at least I can not see a way to do it.

Comment: From MSDN: Note that you cannot use the MethodInfo object from the base class to invoke the overridden method in the derived class, because late binding cannot resolve overrides.

Comment: @JeffN825: I figured I might be wrong in this one, but I'll keep the answer because I still have to test if its really possible and this is one feature I would really not like. Accesing base implementation through a derived type is in a way breaking the derived type implementation and who knows what can come out of that. Anyhow, one of the drawbacks of reflection is that it allows you to do things you shouldn't be able to, but we can live with it because its darn useful :p. I just wish, in this case, that my answer were right.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but it *is* possible using base.Property, so I thought that there might be some Reflect-Ninja way of doing it aswell.

Comment: @Max: I might be wrong on this one. Try what JeffN825 says, it seems plausible that it should work.

Comment: @InBetween I will. But I see what you mean, this is not exactly a very clean approach. But the *other* way I can see of doing this transparently is by keeping track of what properties has been set, i.e keeping a dictionary/index which requires alot of code...

Comment: I hate to suggest this, but you can always emit IL for this.

Comment: @Max: You could always implement in the derived type read only properties `PropertyXIsDefaultValue` and set them accordingly through the overriden `PropertyX` setter: `if (value == null) propertyXIsDefaultValue = true;`. Its not pretty and probably tedious but its plausible. This amounts to what you have said so you have probably considered this already.

Comment: @InBetween true, and I might go that way anyway, had my eyes on it since reflection is not exactly lightning-boltly-fast. Still not 100% sure any of this is a good way to go, so I might change it completely ;)

Comment: @Jeff @InBetween See my edits above, I might have misunderstood what you were getting at.

Comment: @Max: I am now almost positive it is not possible to get the base implementation through reflection. See edits to my post.